# Else response not being printed (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Sorry if this is a horrible post, but I'm new to this site and to coding in general. This code that I've written doesn't print the **else** statement when it should (typing anything other than "yes" or "Yes"). In other words, it always prints: Fantastic! I'm sorry if this is a very basic question, but I've just started coding a few days ago (I really like it!).

```
 name = input("What is your name? ")

 day = input("Has your day been going well, Mr. " +name+"? ")

 if day == "yes" or "Yes":

     print ("Fantastic!")

 else:
     print ("I'm sorry.")
```

Comment: Check the linked post. The problem is the `or` isn't working like you think. What you write means `if (day == "yes") or ("Yes")`, which means part of your if is like saying `if "Yes"`. HTH

Comment: You need it to read `if day == "yes" or day == "Yes":`

Comment: ^ Or more commonly either `if day.lower() == "yes"` or `if day in ('yes', 'Yes')`